# How to merge two csv files using multiprocessing with python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, multiprocessing

I want to merge two csv files with common column using python panda
 With 32 bit processor after 2 gb memory it will throw memory error
how can i do the same with multi processing or any other methods

```
import gc
import pandas as pd
csv1_chunk = pd.read_csv('/home/subin/Desktop/a.txt',dtype=str, iterator=True, chunksize=1000)
csv1 = pd.concat(csv1_chunk, axis=1, ignore_index=True)
csv2_chunk = pd.read_csv('/home/subin/Desktop/b.txt',dtype=str, iterator=True, chunksize=1000)
csv2 = pd.concat(csv2_chunk, axis=1, ignore_index=True)
new_df = csv1[csv1["PROFILE_MSISDN"].isin(csv2["L_MSISDN"])]
new_df.to_csv("/home/subin/Desktop/apyb.txt", index=False)
gc.collect()
```

please help me to fix this

thanks in advance

Comment: Multiprocessing won't help you with memory error. How large are your files? Can you load one or both of them into memory without an error?

Comment: its having 50 million rows any other methods?

Answer (score 0):

I think you only need one column from your second file (actually, only unique elements from this column are needed), so there is no need to load the whole data frame.

```
import pandas as pd

csv2 = pd.read_csv('/home/subin/Desktop/b.txt', usecols=['L_MSISDN'])
unique_msidns = set(csv2['L_MSISDN'])
```

If this still gives a memory error, try doing this in chunks:

```
chunk_reader = pd.read_csv('/home/subin/Desktop/b.txt', usecols=['L_MSISDN'], chunksize=1000)
unique_msidns = set()
for chunk in chunk_reader:
    unique_msidns = unique_msidns | set(chunk['L_MSIDNS'])
```

Now, we can deal with the first data frame.

```
chunk_reader = pd.read_csv('/home/subin/Desktop/a.txt', chunksize=1000)
for chunk in chunk_reader:
    bool_idx = chunk['PROFILE_MSISDN'].isin(unique_msidns)
    # *append* selected lines from every chunk to a file (mode='a')
    # col names are not written
    chunk[bool_idx].to_csv('output_file', header=False, index=False, mode='a')
```

If you need column names to be written into the output file, you can do it with the first chunk (I've skipped it for code clarity).

I believe it's safe (and probably faster) to increase `chunksize`.

I didn't test this code, so be sure to double check it.